# Row-wise correlation between two matrices

Tags: r, matrix, statistics, pearson-correlation, multi-dimensional-scaling

I have the following matrices :

[image: EurodistCL.scl]

And:

[image: EurodistM.scl]

I want to calculate their row-wise pearson correlations and I've tried these pieces of code:

```
RowCor<- sapply(1:21, function(i) cor(EurodistCL.scl[i,], EurodistM.scl[i,], method = "pearson"))
```

And:

```
cA <- EurodistCL.scl - rowMeans(EurodistCL.scl)
cB <- EurodistM.scl- rowMeans(EurodistM.scl)
sA <- sqrt(rowMeans(cA^2))
sB <- sqrt(rowMeans(cB^2))
rowMeans(cA * cB) / (sA * sB)
```

Both give the same output, a correlation vector of 21 ones.

Although the matrices are clearly highly correlated, they are not perfectly correlated so I would expect some correlation coefficient to be 0.99 or 0.98

Why am I getting only ones? Is something wrong in the code or in the theory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because you have **only two values** in a row. Even random values would give (+ or -) 1. Try this

```
a <- runif(2)
b <- runif(2)
cor(a, b)
```

So, it is the theory that is incorrect. Although one can get a coefficient of correlation with two samples, it is of little use.

To estimate correlation coefficient, you need more than two corresponding samples.

Comment: I believe I'm not getting it. Where should I put the runifs in the code? I would like to calculate how the coordinates of the cities of the first matrix  correlate with the coordinates of the cities of the second matrix? Isn't a row-wise correlation a good measure?

Comment: Consider `a` and `b` to be corresponding rows in the two matrices. I am trying to demonstrate why you are always getting 1. You should get 1 but it is meaningless.  The problem is you have only two values (here columns). When ever you have only two values you always get correlation of 1.

Comment: Ok, thank you I was totally misunderstanding how a row-wise correlation works. So if I want to see how those matrices differ coordinates-wise and how much they are correlated what measures should I look into?

Comment: This isn't because the correlation is row-wise. It is because there wasn't enough columns.

Comment: As to what you should do, it is not clear what you are trying to do. Maybe post that as a separate question with more explation.